# Starting Titanium "activity" from android service

Tags: android, service, titanium, communication

I have a native module with a listener that starts running on boot.
For certain events I need to perform something similar to startActivity.
Does anyone know what is the equivalent in Titanium or any other ideas
to communicate back to the application?

Thanks,
  Simon

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this kind of activity? I've used this one to alert the user if he wants to exit the application.

```
var mainActivity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;

$.dialog.on('click', function(e){
    if (e.index == 0){
        mainActivity.finish();
    }
    else
        Ti.API.info('You clicked NO');  
});
```

Maybe this link will be useful: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android-property-currentActivity

Comment: I need to open an activity with a web view